# Keras / TensorFlow: concatenating layer of constants to a convolution

Tags: tensorflow, keras

For each convolution activation map, I want to concatenate a layer of constants -- more particularly, I want to concatenate a meshgrid. (This is to reproduce a paper from Uber.)

For example, say I have an activation map of `(?, 256, 256, 32)`; then I want to concatenate a constants layer of shape `(?, 256, 256, 1)`.

This is how I am doing this:

```
from keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_layer = layers.Input((256, 256, 3))
conv = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(input_layer)
print('conv:', conv.shape)


xx, yy = np.mgrid[:256, :256]  # [(256, 256), (256, 256)]
xx = tf.constant(xx, np.float32)
yy = tf.constant(yy, np.float32)

xx = tf.reshape(xx, (-1, 256, 256, -1))
yy = tf.reshape(yy, (-1, 256, 256, -1))
print('xx:', xx.shape, 'yy:', yy.shape)

concat = layers.Concatenate()([conv, xx, yy])
print('concat:', concat.shape)

conv2 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(concat)
print('conv2:', conv2.shape)
```

But I get the error:

```
conv: (?, 256, 256, 32)
xx: (?, 256, 256, ?) yy: (?, 256, 256, ?)
concat: (?, 256, 256, ?)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "temp.py", line 21, in <module>
conv2 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(concat)
[...]
raise ValueError('The channel dimension of the inputs '
ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. Found `None`.
```

The problem is that my constants layer is `(?, 256, 256, ?)`, instead of `(?, 256, 256, 1)`, and then the next convolution layers errors-out.

I have tried other things without success.

PS: The paper I was trying to implement is already [implemented here](https://github.com/titu1994/keras-coordconv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [tf.reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) can't infer the shape of more than one dimension (i.e. using `-1` for more than one dimension results in undefined dimensions `?`). Since you want the shapes of `xx` and `yy` to be `(?, 256, 256, 1)`, you could reshape these tensors as follows:

```
xx = tf.reshape(xx, (-1, 256, 256, 1))
yy = tf.reshape(yy, (-1, 256, 256, 1))
```

The resulting shapes will be `(1, 256, 256, 1)`. Now, `conv` is `(?, 256, 256, 32)`, and [keras.layers.Concatenate](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate) requires the shapes of all the inputs to match except for the concat axis. You could then use [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) to repeat tensors `xx` and `yy` along the first dimension in order to match the batch size:

```
xx = tf.tile(xx, [tf.shape(conv)[0], 1, 1, 1])
yy = tf.tile(yy, [tf.shape(conv)[0], 1, 1, 1])
```

The shapes of `xx` and `yy` are now `(?, 256, 256, 1)`, and the tensors can be concatenated because their first dimension matches the batch size.

Comment: I didn't know I could pass along a shape that is not yet defined - thank you!